# How do i find my unique-ID and target it via e.target in order to change something in a generated Div?

Tags: javascript

im working on a ToDoList. Whenever you add a task it generates a DIV which also creates a uniqueID. I need to target a checkbox in that unique Div and if its checked change background color of input and if it is not checked to go back to normal.

The way i had it set up originally didn't work because if i had more than 1 checkbox, everything would stop working. After doing some research and creating unique ID, how can I target it without knowing what it is?

Basically something like e.target.parentElement and that unique ID, then if it is checked > change background color, if its clicked again and unchecked, that means the task is not finished.

Someone suggested to use data-id for id and then target it with querySelector but i am not sure what that looks like exactly.

Thank you so much!

Please see code below.

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const toDoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const toDoUi = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
const editBtn = document.querySelector("edit-btn");

addButton.addEventListener("click", addToDoItem);
toDoUi.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);
toDoUi.addEventListener("click", completeItem);
toDoUi.addEventListener("click", editItem);

let randomId = "";

function getRandomId() {
  randomId = new Date().getTime().toString();
}

getRandomId();

function addToDoItem(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("todo");
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = `
    <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="${randomId}">
    <input type="text" class="generated-input" value="${toDoInput.value}" disabled="disabled">`;
  li.classList.add("todo-item");
  div.append(li);

  getRandomId();

  const editButton = document.createElement("button");
  editButton.classList.add("edit-btn");
  editButton.innerText = "Edit";
  div.append(editButton);

  const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.classList.add("delete-btn");
  deleteButton.innerText = `Delete`;
  div.append(deleteButton);

  toDoUi.append(div);

  toDoInput.value = "";
}

function deleteItem(e) {
  if (e.target.classList[0] === "delete-btn") {
    const todo = e.target.parentElement;
    todo.remove();
  }
}

function editItem(e) {
  if (e.target.classList[0] === "edit-btn") {
    e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".generated-input").disabled = false;
    e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".generated-input").focus();
    e.target.classList.add("hideBtn");

    const saveButton = document.createElement("button");
    saveButton.className = "save-btn";
    saveButton.innerText = "Save";
    e.target.parentElement.firstChild.append(saveButton);

    document.querySelector(".save-btn").addEventListener("click", saveItem);

    function saveItem() {
      e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".generated-input").disabled = true;
      e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".save-btn").remove();
      e.target.parentElement
        .querySelector(".edit-btn")
        .classList.remove("hideBtn");
    }
  }
}

function completeItem(e) {
  const checkedMark = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  if (checkedMark) {
    e.target
      .closest(".todo")
      .querySelector(".generated-input")
      .classList.add("test");
  }

  if (document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')) console.log("working");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
}

body,
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: #312c56;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

img,
picture,
svg,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.width-restriction {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: hsla(0, 6%, 93%, 0.803);
  width: 100%;

  border-radius: 15px;
}

header {
  padding: 0.8em;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.todo-input {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-style: none;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus {
  outline-color: #e348c4;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.todo-button {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #e348c4;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.todo-button:hover {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ba00fd;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo-list {
  width: 100%;
}

.todo-item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.todo-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.todo {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.edit-btn,
.delete-btn,
.save-btn {
  width: 12%;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #e348c4;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.edit-btn:hover,
.delete-btn:hover,
.save-btn:hover {
  background-color: #ba00fd;
}

.generated-input {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-style: none;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 76%;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding-left: 7em;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

.completed {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.hideBtn {
  display: none;
}

.save-btn {
  padding: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: "\002714";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  opacity: 0.5;
  content: "";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: "\002714";
  font-size: 20px;
}

.test {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-container width-restriction">
    <header>Alex's To Do List</header>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="todo-input">
        <button class="todo-button" type="submit">Add ToDo</button>
    </form>
    <h3>Tasks</h3>
    <div class="todo-container">
        <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Stuff like this should be done without relying on IDs. Make use of the relation the elements have to each other in the DOM. For example after you went up to the common parent element, you can then use methods like querySelector/querySelectorAll _on_ that element, to only search among its descendants.

Comment: _"I need to target a checkbox in that unique Div and if its checked change background color of input and if it is not checked to go back to normal"_ - if that is _all_ you need, and we are talking about a structure where the checkbox comes before the input field on the same level - then this part doesn't even need any JS at all, CSS can do that - keywords `:checked` pseudo class, and _adjacent sibling combinator_.

Comment: That doesn't work because when there is more than one Div and they all have the same class or checkbox, for example input[type:checkbox]:checked.....it stops working since there is more than one.

Comment: What are you talking about, you have each of those checkbox-input field combos in a separate LI, no? _"it stops working since there is more than one"_ - only the input field immediately following the checkbox input would be selected in the first place with the adjacent sibling combinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `input` element in the `completeItem` function and add/remove the `.test` class to it. i made some changes to your `completeItem` function below.

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const toDoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const toDoUi = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
const editBtn = document.querySelector("edit-btn");

addButton.addEventListener("click", addToDoItem);
toDoUi.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);
toDoUi.addEventListener("click", completeItem);
toDoUi.addEventListener("click", editItem);

let randomId = "";

function getRandomId() {
  randomId = new Date().getTime().toString();
}

getRandomId();

function addToDoItem(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("todo");
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = `
    <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="${randomId}">
    <input type="text" class="generated-input" value="${toDoInput.value}" disabled="disabled">`;
  li.classList.add("todo-item");
  div.append(li);

  getRandomId();

  const editButton = document.createElement("button");
  editButton.classList.add("edit-btn");
  editButton.innerText = "Edit";
  div.append(editButton);

  const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.classList.add("delete-btn");
  deleteButton.innerText = `Delete`;
  div.append(deleteButton);

  toDoUi.append(div);

  toDoInput.value = "";
}

function deleteItem(e) {
  if (e.target.classList[0] === "delete-btn") {
    const todo = e.target.parentElement;
    todo.remove();
  }
}

function editItem(e) {
  if (e.target.classList[0] === "edit-btn") {
    e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".generated-input").disabled = false;
    e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".generated-input").focus();
    e.target.classList.add("hideBtn");

    const saveButton = document.createElement("button");
    saveButton.className = "save-btn";
    saveButton.innerText = "Save";
    e.target.parentElement.firstChild.append(saveButton);

    document.querySelector(".save-btn").addEventListener("click", saveItem);

    function saveItem() {
      e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".generated-input").disabled = true;
      e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".save-btn").remove();
      e.target.parentElement
        .querySelector(".edit-btn")
        .classList.remove("hideBtn");
    }
  }
}

function completeItem(e) {
  const itemWrapper = e.target.closest(".todo");
  if(!itemWrapper) return;
  const checkedMark = itemWrapper.querySelector("[type=checkbox]");
  const input = itemWrapper.querySelector("[type=text]")
  if (checkedMark.checked)
    input.classList.add("test");
  else
    input.classList.remove("test");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
}

body,
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: #312c56;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

img,
picture,
svg,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.width-restriction {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: hsla(0, 6%, 93%, 0.803);
  width: 100%;

  border-radius: 15px;
}

header {
  padding: 0.8em;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.todo-input {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-style: none;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus {
  outline-color: #e348c4;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.todo-button {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #e348c4;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.todo-button:hover {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ba00fd;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo-list {
  width: 100%;
}

.todo-item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.todo-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.todo {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.edit-btn,
.delete-btn,
.save-btn {
  width: 12%;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #e348c4;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.edit-btn:hover,
.delete-btn:hover,
.save-btn:hover {
  background-color: #ba00fd;
}

.generated-input {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-style: none;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 76%;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding-left: 7em;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

.completed {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.hideBtn {
  display: none;
}

.save-btn {
  padding: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: "\002714";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  opacity: 0.5;
  content: "";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: "\002714";
  font-size: 20px;
}

.test {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-container width-restriction">
    <header>Alex's To Do List</header>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="todo-input">
        <button class="todo-button" type="submit">Add ToDo</button>
    </form>
    <h3>Tasks</h3>
    <div class="todo-container">
        <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes more sense, I didn't think of the first IF statement.